Divorced(?) father on cruise (boat) with children (daughter & son)
I'm looking for a movie - possibly TV-movie.  It's English-language, probably American.  I think it's from the 1980s or possibly 1990s.  It's a romantic drama.
It's about a father taking his children on cruise with a cruise-ship.  I think he's divorced and going without the children's mother... but I guess it's possible he's trying to salvage the marriage and/or re-kindle the relationship with the children's mother, and she's on board (I think so though).
There are two children; an older girl and a younger boy.  I think the girl's about 11-12, but I guess she could be 9.  I think the boy is about 7 - but I guess if the girl was only 9, he could be as young as 5.
Anyway, the father does find romance on the boat, and starts a relationship with a woman.
I particularly remember two scenes:

A woman who's been talking to the father leaves, and he follows her with his eyes as she go through a doorway (into an elevator?).  He's son and daughter has been watching (from behind some potted plants/palms?), and their conversation goes something like this:

boy: What's he looking at?
girl: Her butt.
boy: Why?
girl: Because he's a man.
boy: When I grow up, I won't be looking at women's butts!
girl: You will!

The other scene, is during a ball on board.  Where the girl dances with her father - possibly standing on his shoes.  I think he complements her dress, and she looks down shyly for a moment.  I think the dress was white.  
It's possible that the woman the father met, helped the girl pick-out the dress.  (I sort of vaguely think I remember that).

Does this sounds familiar to anybody?

You're thinking of Table for Five with Jon Voight playing the father of divorce, who wants to vacation with his kids to help reconnect. While away, their mother dies and the stepfather (Richard Crenna) wants to take custody away, cancelling the remainder of the trip and returning them home.
From imdb:
J. P. Tannen takes his three children for a vacation cruise. They usually live with their mother and step-father, but now J. P. feels capable of taking them. Emotional tragedy strikes, causing battles parent against parent, and parent against child. J. P. tries to show his children that he loves them.
